# Keep getting not delegated when doing Marshal.load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function on my controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
 before_action :fetch_books,
               only: %i[index]

 def index; end

 private

 def fetch_books
    books = $redis.get("books")
    if books.nil?
      all_books = Book.all
      @books = all_books.map { |book| BookDecorator.new(book) }
      $redis.set('books', Marshal.dump(@books))
    else
      @books = Marshal.load(books)
    end
  end
end
```

Im doing a simple caching using Marshal with redis, the reason why I'm using Marshal and not JSON because Book model has a delegator class and I don't want to lose that information when deserializing back.

```
class BookDecorator < SimpleDelegator
   def calculate_something

   end
end
```

but whenever I tried to deserialize the object back - `@books = Marshal.load(books)`

I get

> ArgumentError in BooksController#index not delegated

I'm not sure what to do

Comment: Do you really need to reinvent the caching wheel? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: Can u share the whole stack trace?